How to update a Room Flow using multiple database instances?
I'm trying to live count some value, when I insert stuff in db and get it with getCount() it is returning it well, but I want to live update Text in Bar. It updates after app restart, but not updating live, am I missing something?
Viewmodel:
@HiltViewModel
class appViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val appDao: appDao
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _Count = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val Count: StateFlow<Int> = _Count.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            appDao.getCount()
                .collect { count ->
                    _Count.value = count
                }
        }
    }
}

Bar:
@Composable
fun WkTopBar(navController: NavController?) {

    val appViewModel: appViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val Count by appViewModel.Count.collectAsState()

    Text(text = "count: $Count", color = Color.Black)
}

Dao:

@Entity(tableName = "books")
data class Book(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) val id: Int = 0,
    val title: String,
    val body: String,
    val isRead: Boolean = false

)

@Dao
interface appDao {

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertBook(book: Book)

    @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books WHERE isRead = 0")
    fun getCount(): Flow<Int>
}


Database module

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object DatabaseModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideAppDatabase(applicationContext: Context): AppDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext,
            AppDatabase::class.java,
            "book_database"
        ).build()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideAppDao(appDatabase: AppDatabase): appDao {
        return appDatabase.appDao()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideContext(app: Application): Context {
        return app.applicationContext
    }
}


AppDatabase
@Database(entities = [Book::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun appDao(): appDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "book_database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance
            }
        }
    }
}

Inserting (this is done from another class running in another process where I do not use Hilt):
private fun saveBook(message: RemoteMessage) {
        val title = message.book?.title.orEmpty()
        val body = message.book?.body.orEmpty()

        val book = Book(title = title, body = body)

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            try {
                val appDao = AppDatabase.getDatabase(applicationContext).appDao()
                appDao.insertBook(book)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error saving book: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
    }

I tried with Flow and LiveData, but it's not working.

Although a bit wacky, your code seems to work fine as it is. Assuming it is just a typo that your entity is named app while you access table and that it has no something property. Please [edit] your question and fix that. Please also add the code that you use to add new entries. Then verify that the code you provided actually exhibits the problematic behavior.

@Leviathan I provided you with database and inserting function from my class

You use Hilt, so why do you create the a database instance manually in saveBook? Please inject it as you do it with your view model. Also, what is insertApp (I can't find it in the DAO) and what is Book? How is it different from app? And you didn't fix the issues I mentioned in my first comment. Please [edit] again and fix all of the above.

Also you have two different AppDatabase classes in your question. Please remove one.

@Leviathan Issues you mentioned first is typo, ill fix that, and I updated other stuff so you can check why is still not live updating but only after reset.

It's gotten worse. Please fix all compile errors. And you still haven't addressed the issues from my very first comment.

I changed, also I'm creating manually in saveBook because where is that function is not Hilth so thats why I created like that.

The database is only notified about changes if the changes are done with the same database instance. Since you use two different database instances - one for reading (injected by Hilt) and one for writing (manually created) - the changes done by the latter won't automatically trigger an update for the first.
If the code for both runs in the same process then the solution is simple: Use the same instance. The easiest way would be to also use Hilt to inject the database for saveBook. If you don't want to use Hilt for that, make sure you provide the same database instance for Hilt that you use to directly retrieve the dao.
If the code runs in different processes then you need to enable multi-instance invalidation. That allows the database instance that makes changes to broadcast to other database instances that some of their current state is invalid. The other database instances then re-execute their queries to get the updated data. Simply add enableMultiInstanceInvalidation() to both your database builders:
Room.databaseBuilder(/*...*/)
    .enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()
    .build()


Thanks a lot, .enableMultiInstanceInvalidation() fixed my problem.

Edit:
This answer does not contain the actual solution, refer to @Leviathan's answer instead.
old Answer:
Please try to change your appViewModel like this:
@HiltViewModel
class AppViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val appDao: appDao
) : ViewModel() {

    val count = appDao
        .getCount()
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, 0)
}

Then, you can observe it from your Composable like this:
val appViewModel: AppViewModel = hiltViewModel()
val count by appViewModel.count.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

I renamed your ViewModel class and variables to follow the naming conventions of Kotlin.
Finally, check your dependencies in build.gradle, Android Studio will tell you when there are new versions available. Especially check your Compose version, the latest as of now is 1.7.2, and make sure that you have the room-ktx dependency if you are using Room < 2.7.0:
def room_version = "2.6.1"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"  // IMPORTANT!


Note:
The official documentatiom recommends to add one more layer between the ViewModel/UI and the DAO, namely a Repository layer. This repository layer abstracts different kinds of data sources, like a database or API.

In your case, a repository class would simply look like this:
class MyRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val appDao: AppDao
) {
    fun getCount() = appDao.getCount()
}

Then, you inject that into your ViewModel:
@HiltViewModel
class AppViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val myRepo: MyRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val count = myRepo
        .getCount()
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, 0)
}


I also recommend adding additional Repository layer so viewModel does not interact with dao directly

I tried but still not working, again value update only after app reset :/

Also try with collectAsStateWithLifecycle and check the dependencies in your build.gradle. I just tested it on my system, and it works. I edited my post accordingly. If it doesn't in your case, you would need to do some more debugging.

@BenjyTec unfortunately still won't work i have dependencies, also I did everything like you said but it won't work.So the main idea is I have books in database with isRead (true/false) and I have a top navigation bar.The main idea is to count all isRead = false books so in a meanwhile if book is done to live update count but it won't work.Inserting or editing in database works I tested it and the main problem as I can see with my code i provided on start is if i Log something there in viewmodel it log only on start of the app, so the problem is that viewmodel is not recognizing changes inbase

So I want everytime if I am in app and book change isRead to live update and avoid restarting app to show number in top bar.

@BenjyTec I also provide a Database Module maybe its something wrong

@s0mething001 It looks fine to me... Is there anything unusual printed in the logcat? Also, you can try to set up a new mini-project in Android Studio just with the functionality for testing inserting items into the database and updating the count and see if it works there.

@BenjyTec I provide you guys with database code and inserting function can you check is something wrong there, I'm still struggling with this problem.

Change your DAO interface like this:
@Dao
interface AppDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM table")
    fun getAllItems(): Flow<Entity>
}

Then in viewModel you can collect this flow with filter operator.
init {
  viewModelScope.launch {
    appDao.getAllItems()
      .filter { it.something == 0 }
      .collect { list ->
        _Count.value = list.size
      }
  }
}

I also suggest to use count state like below:
val count = appDao.getAllItems()
    .filter { it.something == 0 }
    .map { it.size }
    .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(3_000), 0)


The filter { it.something == 0 } should be redundant, as the OP already filters for that in the @Query.

Thanks for point it out. I edited the answer
